# Update and get value in a single call MongoDb C# SDK

Tags: c#, mongodb, sdk

I am using Upsert method provided by mongoDB to increment one of the field of desired document of a collection in mongoDb. I need a call to upsert the value first and second call to get the upserted value. This seems redundant, does anyone know how to achieve this using single call, it may be using SDK or API.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No you will need to do this in 2 separate calls.

You can use the response of the operation (UpdateResult) to determine if the operation modified any documents, or whether it upserted a new document, and in the case of the later, retrieve the Id of the newly created document. But to increment a field and return the new value in a single query isn't possible.

Comment: He doesn't. He wants the value after incremental update: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/

Comment: I see, I have updated my answer, either way, it would need to be a separate operation. You cannot update and retrieve in a single operation with MongoDB

Comment: Yeah, Alex Blex I don't know the value since it is an incremental update.

Comment: Is it possible from API call using RestClient?

Comment: The mongodb engine will not allow you to write and retrieve in a single call. You would need to perform 2 operations, one to write, and one to retrieve

Comment: @pieperu, Yes, but it opens a window for a race condition. Consider 2 requests upserting the same document, then reading it. With unlucky timing it can be 2 writes, then 2 reads.

Comment: I agree. The question was "is it possible in a single call", the answer is "no"